# Is there a way to get a scope of a DOM element when debug info is disabled?

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing an directive which need to retrieve a scope of current DOM element. using the non public api `angular.element().scope();`

It works well until angular 1.3 introduces a new feature `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);` which mainly aims to improve performance to avoid bind data in DOM element. But when debugInfoEnabled()  is set to false, `angular.element().scope()` will return `undefined`. So I must find another way to get the scope of an DOM element or I have to redesign my code logic.

Is there a way to make this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just faced a similar problem in our application after compiling our app with `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);`.  I needed to later access some of our directive's isolate scope but couldn't use the `isolateScope()` method.  To get around the problem, I created a helper function in a Utils service that looks like this:

```
this.setElementIsolateScope = function(element, scope) {
    element[0].isolateScope = function() {
        return scope;
    };
};
```

Then inside any directive where I needed to be able to later access the isolate scope I called this function inside the `link()` function:  Since `element` is a jqLite object, you need to set the `isolateScope()` function on `element[0]`. You should already have the jqLite wrapped `element` and `scope` already passed into your link function, which you then just pass to your service method.

```
Utils.setElementIsolateScope(element, scope);
```

To then access the isolate scope later, you would get a reference to your element and then do this (assuming `child_element` is the reference to your element/directive):

```
var child_iso_scope = _.isFunction(child_element.isolateScope) && child_element.isolateScope();
```

Depending on how you are getting the reference to your element, you may need to wrap it a jqLite wrapper like this:

```
child_element = angular.element(child_element);
```

And then just use the same way as above to get the isolate scope.  Hope this helps!

Comment: unfortunately this will work only for the parent element of the directive. The isolateScope won't be available for all the children nodes