# Get scope from DOM element with $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to take advantage of AngularJS new fetures. One of them is :

```
$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
```

The thing is that some pieces of my code rely on `angular.element(el).scope()` calls. So they won't work any longer.

Is there a way to rewrite `angular.element(el).scope()` expression to somehow get element's scope without debug info enabled?

Comment: I guess you need to get all scopes - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514147/in-angularjs-how-do-you-find-all-the-scopes-on-a-page - and manually search from it. attach $scope to dom manually to access it later.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/29833832/2460773

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
angular.element(el).controller()
```

Then you can access your scope functions and variables.

Comment: not working for me. Are you sure you executed this with debug info turned off?

Comment: Does this work with debug info turned off (Angular version 1.4.9)? It does not seem to to work for me.

Comment: not working for me either with the debug turned off.

Answer (score -2):

type in console:

```
angular.reloadWithDebugInfo();
```